# How to check if form is valid in ts?

Tags: angular

I have this in html:

```
             <input class="ui-g-4 right" name="unitprice" pattern="(0\.((0[1-9]{1})|([1-9]{1}([0-9]{1})?)))|(([1-9]+[0-9]*)(\.([0-9]{1,2}))?)" [(ngModel)]="product.unitprice" (focusout)="addDecimal(i)" (ngModelChange)="product.unitprice = $event;sumTotal(i)">
```

What i want is to check on focusout if its ok if not to show some message.
Any suggestion?

Comment: you can use reactive form method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this

```
[(ngModel)]="product.unitprice"
```

With this

```
[formControl]="unitprice"
```

In your TS, create this

```
unitprice: FormControl = new FormControl(this.product.unitprice, [
  Validators
    .pattern((0\.((0[1-9]{1})|([1-9]{1}([0-9]{1})?)))|(([1-9]+[0-9]*)(\.([0-9]{1,2}))?))
]);
```

Now you can check for errors, and apply a class to your input with this

```
[class.has-error]="unitprice.hasError('pattern')"
```

Or in your TS

```
if (!this.unitprice.hasError('pattern')) { /* valid value */ }
```

Comment: where in ts to put this unitprice: FormControl........ ?

Comment: In your class, as a variable, before your constructor ...

Comment: i mean this part of code : unitprice: FormControl = new FormControl(this.product.unitprice, [
  Validators
    .pattern((0\.((0[1-9]{1})|([1-9]{1}([0-9]{1})?)))|(([1-9]+[0-9]*)(\.([0-9]{1,2}))?))
]);

Comment: And I meant In your class, as a variable, before your constructor

Comment: but i dont see product.unitprice because i display that in foreach and then i get an error Cannot read property 'unitprice' of undefined

Comment: replace `this.product.unitprice` by `''` : I thought you had a product, but it appears you are probably requesting it from your backend

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
[(ngModel)]="product.unitprice"
```

With this

```
[formControl]="price"
```

And in you ts file:

```
private priceInput:FormControl;

ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.priceInput = new FormControl(null, {
       validators: Validators.pattern((0\.((0[1-9]{1})|([1-9]{1}([0-9]{1})?)))|(([1-9]+[0-9]*)(\.([0-9]{1,2}))?)),
       updateOn: 'blur'
    });
}
```

and now in your html file:

```
<div *ngIf="priceInput.hasError">Your Error message</div>
```